# Can you store a Spell Glyph with a spell scroll of a non-prepared spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Spell Glyph section of the [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) spellsays:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph.

The key word that makes me wonder is "prepared".

**If you have a spell scroll of a spell that is on your spell list but you don't have it prepared, are you considered to have it "prepared" by having the spell scroll for the purpose of scribing it using *glyph of warding*?**

Example: Bob the Wizard has *glyph of warding* prepared and has a scroll of *haste* (but did not prepare *haste* today). Can he spell glyph the *haste*?

Answer (score 11):

### You Probably Can't Do This

The meaning of "prepared spell" can be confusing: like "attack" or "action", it is a term with flexible meaning in English, but also a fixed technical meaning in the game. Usually, it means a spell which is selected by members of certain classes at the end of a long rest, and is thus available throughout the day to be cast via spell slots. At first glance, this implies that spells cast via Magic Items are not "prepared spells."

But this is complicated by the fact that Glyph of Warding is on the Bard's spell list, but Bards do not "prepare" their spells in the sense stated above. So you might think that "prepared" spells could apply to any spell you are ready to cast.

That being said, a notable distinction is drawn between spells that are "prepared" and cast from a magic item on page 201 of the PHB.

> **Known and Prepared Spells:** Before a spellcaster can use a spell, he or she must have the spell firmly fixed in mind, or must have access to the spell in a magic item. Members of a few classes, including bards and sorcerers, have a limited list of spells they know that are always fixed in mind. The same thing is true of many magic-using monsters. Other spellcasters, such as clerics and wizards, undergo a process of preparing spells. This process varies for different classes, as detailed in their descriptions.
>
> In every case, the number of spells a caster can have fixed in mind at any given time depends on the character’s level.

In this text, we see that spells which are "prepared" are "fixed in mind." We also see that spells which are "fixed in mind" and spells cast through a magic item are two different categories.

Although this doesn't settle the debate definitively, it does highly imply that spells cast through a magic item are in a separate category than those which are "prepared." And since Spell Scrolls are considered a Magic Item (DMG, p. 200), it is likely that spells cast via their use could not be stored in a Glyph of Warding.

### But...

Naturally, your DM will have to make a ruling. They could be convinced that the "prepared" term in Glyph of Warding's description refers to how the Glyph "prepares" the spell to be cast when triggered. Or maybe they might just figure that Glyph of Warding already takes so much planning and foresight to use (an hour of casting and 200 gp in materials) that it won't make too much difference if you expand its use to spells cast via magic items.

The rules don't lay out an unambiguous path, so each DM will need to decide. But the only guidance laid out in the rules does suggest that your proposed strategy is unlikely to work.

Comment: Is a scroll sufficient to meet the "in a magic item" criterion?  *or must have access to the spell in a magic item* ... I can see why your answer is 'probably not'

Comment: The bard's only option for glyph of warding is the explosive runes.  It's still a usable spell.

Comment: A solution to the Bard problem is shown here: "[Can a Bard use the Spell Glyph option of the Glyph of Warding spell and cast a known spell into the glyph?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146878)"

Answer (score 3):

## One Cannot Store a Non-Prepared Spell in a Spell Glyph.

A [prepared spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#KnownandPreparedSpells) has defined meaning in the context of the basic rule sets.  The definition does not default to a common English meaning.

The class features of the [cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#ClassFeatures) or [wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures) detail how they go about preparing spells.

Comment: (As mentioned by Gandalfmeansme) I think the real fly in the ointment here is the Bard version.  With this strict interpretation a Bard can never cast this spell (unless he's a Bard/Cleric or Bard/Wizard).

Comment: @ReginaldBlue The bard would have to multiclass or be relegated to using explosive runes of Glyph of Warding